# Dapper - QueryMultiple - 3 tables

Tags: dapper

I had this relation:
[image: Order Link Invoice tables]

How to retrieve the information in an order entity and invoice entity with a QueryMultiple entity ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`QueryMultiple` is used when you are accessing multiple result sets, i.e. multiple `select`, as in:

```
select * from Order where Id=@id
select * from Invoice where Id = (...probably some sub-query)
```

At the moment, there is no inbuilt API to stitch this type of query together; instead you would do something like:

```
using(var multi = conn.QueryMultiple(...)) {
    var order = multi.ReadSingle<Order>();
    order.Invoice = multi.ReadSingleOrDefault<Invoice>(); // could be null if 0 rows
    return order;
}
```

I would like to *add* an improved API for this scenario, but it is very awkward to express "join this to that using this property as the association, where {this}.{SomeMember} equals {that}.{SomeOtherMember}".

However, if you are actually doing a single query, as in:

```
select o.*, i.*
from Order o
left outer join Link l on ...
left outer join Invoice i on ...
where o.Id = @id
```

then you can use the various `Query<,...,>` overloads; for example:

```
int id = ...
var order = conn.Query<Order, Invoice, Order>(sql,
    (x,y) => {x.Invoice = y; return x;}, args: new { id }, splitOn: "NumOrder").Single();
```

Answer (score 1):

Generic code for three tables:

```
public static Tuple<IEnumerable<T1>, IEnumerable<T2>, IEnumerable<T3>> ExecuteQueryMultiple<T1, T2, T3>(string sql, object parameters,
                                        Func<GridReader, IEnumerable<T1>> func1,
                                        Func<GridReader, IEnumerable<T2>> func2,
                                        Func<GridReader, IEnumerable<T3>> func3)
        {
            var objs = getMultiple(sql, parameters, func1, func2, func3);
            return Tuple.Create(objs[0] as IEnumerable<T1>, objs[1] as IEnumerable<T2>, objs[2] as IEnumerable<T3>);
        }

private static List<object> getMultiple(string procedureName, object param, params Func<GridReader, object>[] readerFuncs)
        {
            var returnResults = new List<object>();
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                var gridReader = sqlCon.QueryMultiple(procedureName, param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

                foreach (var readerFunc in readerFuncs)
                {
                    var obj = readerFunc(gridReader);
                    returnResults.Add(obj);
                }
            }
            return returnResults;
        }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetCommodityDetails(int ID)
        {
            var data = new List<Commodity>();
            DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
            param.Add("@ATTRIBUTETYPE", "Your parameter");
            param.Add("@CID", Your parameter);
            var result = DapperORM.ExecuteQueryMultiple("Store procedure name", param, gr => gr.Read<order>(), gr => gr.Read<Invoice>(), gr => gr.Read<Link>());

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

You can use this concept. It worked for me